# Anchor tag not working, page scrolls and immediately returns to the top of the page

Tags: html, anchor

Here is my site, http://www.hannahkennell.com/curriculum-vitae/
There is an issue with the Table of Contents, the anchor tags do not work...

```
<a href="#AwardsDistinctions">Awards/Distinctions</a>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This works for me. What about them isn't working?

Comment: I notice that there is some kind of issue when you click two different  hyperlinks from Table of Contents in quick succession (within a second or two), the second hyperlink click shows the top of the page.

Comment: When in Chrome, only 'Experience' and 'Awards/Distinctions' seem to work. When in Firefox, it seems that if I click on a heading twice it works. I don't know why this is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like there might be something wrong with your js file. I'm thinking front.js file; this is too big to be posted here http://pastebin.com/sYna15QN (I took your front.js file, deminified it, added two lines (124. and 163.). This is a long shot, but please do try it. Here's the minified version http://pastebin.com/XHrFVt1B Try it and let us know if that helps.

EDIT:

basically I've added prevent default (and return false; - just to be sure) inside click event function (second line, and second to last line):

```
        $('body a').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            hostname = $(this).prop('hostname');
            pathname = $(this).prop('pathname');
            qs = $(this).prop('search');
            hash = $(this).prop('hash');
            if (pathname.length > 0) {
                if (pathname.charAt(0) != '/') {
                    pathname = '/' + pathname;
                }
            }
            if ((window.location.hostname == hostname) && (window.location.pathname == pathname) && (window.location.search == qs) && (hash !== '')) {
                var hash_selector = hash.replace(/([ !"$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~])/g, '\\$1');
                if ($(hash_selector).length > 0)
                    target = hash;
                else {
                    anchor = hash;
                    anchor = anchor.replace('#', '');
                    target = 'a[name="' + anchor + '"]';
                    if ($(target).length == 0)
                        target = '';
                }
                if (typeof tocplus.smooth_scroll_offset != 'undefined') {
                    offset = -1 * tocplus.smooth_scroll_offset;
                } else {
                    if ($('#wpadminbar').length > 0) {
                        if ($('#wpadminbar').is(':visible'))
                            offset = -30;
                        else
                            offset = 0;
                    } else
                        offset = 0;
                }
                if (target) {
                    $.smoothScroll({
                        scrollTarget: target,
                        offset: offset
                    });
                }
            }
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: Could you post what you changed here? Links have a habit of disappearing over time.

Answer (score -1):

You should remove # which is written in front of Awards/Distinctions in order to redirect.

Comment: But the anchor is going to somewhere on the same page.

Comment: In your site,when I click Awards/Distinctions,it takes downwards on the same page,when i remove #,it redirects me to the page http://www.hannahkennell.com/curriculum-vitae/AwardsDistinctions. Where exactly should your anchor tag take you or redirect you??

Comment: As without it redirects to a 404, I'd suggest that moving on the same page is the correct behaviour.

Comment: In that case, it is working fine according to me. It is taking me to Awards/Distinctions section on the same page. Then where the problem is??

Comment: I agree. See my comment to the question.